# Clipboard.js firing multiple on success events

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard.js

I'm using [Clipboard.js](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js) in a project to allow the user to copy text to their clipboard when a button is pressed.

It works fine, except when I refresh the list of buttons in the list using jQuery it fires multiple on success events. Here's some example code that will reproduce the error:

```
$(function() {
    var data = [
    'Button One',
    'Button Two',
    'Button Three'
];

var refreshButton = $('#refresh').on('click', function(e) {
    var list = $('#buttonList');
    list.empty();

    for(i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        list.append('<li><button class="btn"  data-clipboard-text="Copy Me">' + data[i] + '</button></li>')
    }

    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');
    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        var n = $('body').noty({
        text: 'Link copied to clipboard',
        timeout: 1000,
        type: 'success',
        theme: 'metroui'
        });
        });
  });
});
```

I have created a jsFiddle to reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/jdfj52or/

1. First press the "load list" button
2. Press one of the loaded buttons and you will see a notification
3. Press "load list" again
4. Press one of the loaded buttons and you will 2 notifications

Repeat step 4, and it will continue to repeat more notifications.

Is this an issue with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clipboard.js creator here.

You must destroy the previous instance of Clipboard.js in order to prevent this problem.

```js
if (clipboard) {
  clipboard.destroy();
}
```

Here's the full code and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzq7bfgu/1/):

```js
$(function() {
 var data = [
   'Button One',
    'Button Two',
    'Button Three'
];
var clipboard;

var refreshButton = $('#refresh').on('click', function(e) {
    if (clipboard) {
     clipboard.destroy();
    }

 var list = $('#buttonList');
    list.empty();
    
   for(i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    list.append('<li><button class="btn"  data-clipboard-text="Copy Me">' + data[i] + '</button></li>')
   }
    
    clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');
   clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    var n = $('body').noty({
          text: 'Link copied to clipboard',
          timeout: 1000,
          type: 'success',
          theme: 'metroui'
     });
 });
  });
});
```

Comment: This happens when you have multiple '.btn' (or whatever class you're instrumenting with) buttons on the same page. I couldn't find a way to prevent it within the library, so just added a timer to ignore multiple events with the same text. I'm sure there's a better way.